# Flutter : User Avatar image is not getting updated after I click Save. Other text fields get updated

Tags: django, flutter, dart

I'm using a flutter app connected to my django 3.2 REST api on my GCP Ubuntu VM. My api media folder as defined in my settings.py is ./media ---> which is the root folder of the api.

Since, The profile avatar details doesn't reflect even inside the auth directory under my username , I have narrowed it down to the flutter app itself which is not sending the image to the backend.

Besides, here is what happens on the frontend : The profile pic gets shown inside the profile box after using pick image but it fails(Nothing happens) when I click save which sends a http patch request and returns a success from backend But, the profile picture is again empty. This is something that I'm not able to figure on my own, I'm uploading the avatar file flutter code below:

```html
enum MYAvatarSize { extraSmall, small, medium, large, extraLarge }

enum MYAvatarType { user, community }

class MYAvatar extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? avatarUrl;
  final PlatformFile? avatarFile;
  final MYAvatarSize? size;
  final VoidCallback? onPressed;
  final double? borderWidth;
  final bool isZoomable;
  final double? borderRadius;
  final double? customSize;

  static const double AVATAR_SIZE_EXTRA_SMALL = 20.0;
  static const double AVATAR_SIZE_SMALL = 30.0;
  static const double AVATAR_SIZE_MEDIUM = 40.0;
  static const double AVATAR_SIZE_LARGE = 80.0;
  static const double AVATAR_SIZE_EXTRA_LARGE = 100.0;
  static const String DEFAULT_AVATAR_ASSET =
      'assets/images/fallbacks/avatar-fallback.jpg';
  static const double avatarBorderRadius = 10.0;

  static double getAvatarSize(MYAvatarSize size) {
    late double avatarSize;

    switch (size) {
      case MYAvatarSize.extraSmall:
        avatarSize = AVATAR_SIZE_EXTRA_SMALL;
        break;
      case MYAvatarSize.small:
        avatarSize = AVATAR_SIZE_SMALL;
        break;
      case MYAvatarSize.medium:
        avatarSize = AVATAR_SIZE_MEDIUM;
        break;
      case MYAvatarSize.large:
        avatarSize = AVATAR_SIZE_LARGE;
        break;
      case MYAvatarSize.extraLarge:
        avatarSize = AVATAR_SIZE_EXTRA_LARGE;
        break;
    }

    return avatarSize;
  }

  const MYAvatar(
      {Key? key, this.avatarUrl,
      this.size = MYAvatarSize.small,
      this.onPressed,
      this.avatarFile,
      this.borderWidth,
      this.isZoomable = false,
      this.borderRadius,
      this.customSize}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MYAvatarSize finalSize = size ?? MYAvatarSize.small;
    double avatarSize = customSize ?? getAvatarSize(finalSize);

    Widget finalAvatarImage;

    if (avatarFile != null) {
      finalAvatarImage = FadeInImage(
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        height: avatarSize,
        width: avatarSize,
        placeholder: const AssetImage(DEFAULT_AVATAR_ASSET),
        image: FileImage(File(avatarFile!.path!)),

      );
    } else if (avatarUrl != null) {
      finalAvatarImage = Image(
          height: avatarSize,
          width: avatarSize,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          image: AdvancedNetworkImage(avatarUrl!,
              useDiskCache: true,
              fallbackAssetImage: DEFAULT_AVATAR_ASSET,
              retryLimit: 0));

      if (isZoomable) {
        finalAvatarImage = GestureDetector(
          child: finalAvatarImage,
          onTap: () {
            MyappNetworkProviderState myappProvider =
                MyappNetworkProvider.of(context);
            myappProvider.dialogService.showZoomablePhotoBoxView(
                imageUrl: avatarUrl!, context: context);
          },
        );
      }
    } else {
      finalAvatarImage = _getAvatarPlaceholder(avatarSize);
    }

    Widget avatar = ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius ?? avatarBorderRadius),
      child: finalAvatarImage,
    );

    if (onPressed == null) return avatar;

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPressed,
      child: avatar,
    );
  }

  Widget _getAvatarPlaceholder(double avatarSize) {
    return Image.asset(
      DEFAULT_AVATAR_ASSET,
      height: avatarSize,
      width: avatarSize,
    );
  }
}
```

The suspicious lines are the following :

```
image: FileImage(File(avatarFile.path))  

image:AdvancedNetworkImage(avatarUrl,...)
```

I was initially getting the following errors on the above statements:

```
The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' ---> for both Lines 1 & 2

The property 'path' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!') ---> for Line 1.
```

I did a quick fix and the resultant code is :

```
image: FileImage(File(avatarFile!.path!))
image: AdvancedNetworkImage(avatarUrl!,...)
```

which are parts of original question. No compile errors but the avatar image doesn't get updated.

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi. I have narrowed down the error to the front end now. The bare minimum code to troubleshoot is uploaded.

Comment: You still need to show a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: Hi. Have added the entire avatar code. Is it fine now ?

Comment: @aaron. Have provided more context. Deleted text which isn't necessary.

Comment: How does your code look where the widget from your snippet is used? Like what is passed as the `onPressed` callback and how do you interact with the image, etc?

Comment: From what I understand what you asked, I click the placeholder, Image appears, I crop the image by clicking the crop icon, the image then displays in the placeholder avatar box. In the page below are the the other text fields. There is just  a save button that I use to save the information. Except profile avatar image, everything else saves.

Comment: @Niko Have I answered your question ?

Comment: Oh sorry, i didn't get a notification. 

Without the code snippets there is not much i can do. 

You said your error is the following: "app itself which is not sending the image to the backend" 

but your provided code snippets only displays your avatar and calls some callback.

Comment: HI @Niko I have added a snippet from edit_profile.dart snippet which calls the MYAvatar(). Let me know if anything else needs to be added ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your new code snippet isn't even using the `onPressed` of your `MYAvatar` and you have another onPressed method that calls another method of your code. 

I think it will be too hard for me to find your problem if you don't have your full source code published on github, or anywhere else.

Comment: @Niko This is the stack i'm using. https://github.com/OkunaOrg/okuna-app/blob/master/lib/widgets/avatars/avatar.dart , Only difference is using PlatformFile instead of File

Comment: @Niko Could you pls check and revert ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this does not help. It is just the same Widget from your code snippet, but not your use case of it. 

Where and how it is used inside of your code? 

Have you forked your own repository of that github repository you linked and are you using the widget in a similar way?

Comment: @Niko. For the media part,  I changed File to PlatformFile of file_picker.dart and made changes accordingly.  Regular posts with media get updated but only profile avatar and coverfile doesn't get updated. Can You point out which method does OnPressed is calling ? I didn't debug the backend, because I do get "PATCH /api/auth/user/ HTTP/1.1" 200 830 response everytime I click Save button which saves profile details. The only issue is the avatarimage and coverimage is not showing in my backend.

Comment: But the Avatar file is not doing any saving, or web communication with data, it only displays your image. The logic for handling the data is somewhere else inside of your code. 

Are you using a near identical fork of the current version of that github repository you posted? 

And then is your "Save" related to one of the following?
https://github.com/OkunaOrg/okuna-app/blob/master/lib/pages/home/pages/profile/pages/edit_profile/modals/edit_profile.dart

or 

https://github.com/OkunaOrg/okuna-app/blob/master/lib/pages/home/modals/save_community.dart

Comment: Hi again. Yes. Only the following two lines have changed in both :                                  
File _avatarFile----> PlatformFile? _avatarFile & File? _coverFile---->PlatformFile? _coverFile;

Comment: Ok, have you also adjusted the `updateUser` method of https://github.com/OkunaOrg/okuna-app/blob/master/lib/services/auth_api.dart#L8 to not be like `if (avatar is File) { body['avatar'] = avatar;`? 

Or have you tried debugging the `updateUser` method of https://github.com/OkunaOrg/okuna-app/blob/ce6040af5b9ed9a41ef304348f8c44a67935fd27/lib/services/user.dart#L421 to see what is send to the server and what is received as a response?

Comment: Hi. Nope. Haven't changed anything there.  I will now try the updateUser debugging based on your directions.

Comment: Hi again. HttpieStreamedResponse response = await _authApiService.updateUser ----> This debug shows the avatarFile path but the bytes are shown as null.

Comment: @Niko Bytes shouldnt be a problem for now. The updateUser does show the media in path. I cant understand what's going wrong.

Comment: Solved. Had to change if (avatar is File) { body['avatar'] = avatar ----> if (avatar is PlatformFile) { body['avatar'] = avatar;

Comment: Hi, sorry that i'm answering only now, i just got home. 

Yes, that line of your last line is needed so that the data still gets send to the server if you also changed the "avatar" everywhere else to "PlatformFile", because otherwise it would send nothing to the server, because it still expects a "File" and not a "PlatformFile".
 
It didn't show up in your initial refactoring, because the "avatar" param of that method is `dynamic`, so it accepts everything. 

Did you have any other errors ,or was that it?

Comment: Hi. No other errors so far. Will do a detail inspection again today.

Comment: That's good! If anything else comes up, feel free to send me another message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to change the updateUser() function which awaits response from the server api backend.

```
if (avatar is File) 
{body['avatar'] = avatar}
```

to

```
if (avatar is PlatformFile) 
{body['avatar'] = avatar}
```

Answer (score 1):

TLDR summarization if anyone has a similar problem and does not want to read all of the comments above.

The problem was the following:
After changing the type of an attribute (here a File for a profile avatar picture) inside of the UI and then adjusting the related code fragments the affected attribute was no longer updated on the backend.

This happened because the api for sending the data from the client to the server (to update the profile) accepted some attributes of the profile as `dynamic` type, so it didn't produce any errors, or warnings on the initial code refactoring.

But inside of that method before converting the attributes of the profile to json, the affected attribute (in this case the dynamic `avatar`), it's type was checked against the old type (so `File` and not the new `Platformfile`) which lead to no data for the attribute being send to the server on updating.